# Idiomatic way to compare possibly-null value with greater than

Tags: javascript, typescript, comparison

Typescript is complaining about an expression of this form:

`if (foo?.length > 3) {`

saying that `foo` is possible undefined (ts18048) , which is true. But if it's true, then `foo?.length` will evaluate to `undefined`, which will not be greater than 3, which is the behaviour I want.

Is there an idiomatic way to reassure TypeScript?

I can do `if (foo && foo.length > 3)` but in this case, `foo` is quite a long expression.

Comment: It shouldn't complain about `foo` being `null` (which is handled by `?.`), rather it should complain about comparing a possibly-`undefined` value to a number.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit loose with my paraphrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatic TypeScript would indeed be to test for `null` explicitly:

```
if (foo != null && foo.length > 3)
```

If `foo` is a longer expression, declare a new variable for it, which you probably also will reuse inside of the `if` block anyway.

However, if that really doesn't suit your needs, you can use nullish coalescing to get a value that TypeScript accepts for the numeric comparison:

```
if (foo?.length ?? 0 > 3)
```

For the length of an array, `0` seems to be a sensible default, for anything else you can also use `+Infinity` or `-Infinity`.